# getting null input in widget,data

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an issue while writing my code
in the main page of my app i'm requesting a get from my json file and receiving a list of users + their info and when tapped on each of these users a new page opens up with some additional information.
in the 2nd page i make a new get request and this is where the problem happens and I get this error:
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building FutureBuilder(dirty, state:              _FutureBuilderState get http
and my widget.data. returns as null
some help would be appreciated.

```
try {
String url =
'http://10.0.0.21:8000/api/users/' + widget.employee.id.toString();
individualData = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));

var test = individualData;
} catch (e) {
print(e.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i forgot to put an  if else to check if data exists

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks, would you please add some code snippets and explain why that code snippets solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

```
String? employeeId = widget.employee.id;

if(employeeId!=null){
try {
String url =
'http://10.0.0.21:8000/api/users/' + employeeId;
individualData = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));

var test = individualData;
} catch (e) {
print(e.toString());
}
}else{
    print('Getting employeeId as null');
}
```

So first check employeeId is not getting a null and then call a API.